# boxplot in ggplot gives unexpected output

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to plot a grouped boxplot using ggplot.  Something like the picture below:

[image]

Below please see a sample (10 rows) from my data:

```
    alpha   colsample_bytree    best_F1
35  0.00    0.5                 0.5825656
78  0.10    0.3                 0.4716612
68  0.00    0.3                 0.4714286
27  0.40    1.0                 0.4786216
49  0.15    0.5                 0.4943968
62  0.00    0.3                 0.4938805
70  0.00    0.3                 0.4849785
73  0.10    0.3                 0.4997061
59  0.30    0.5                 0.4856369
88  0.20    0.3                 0.4552402


   sort(unique(data$alpha))
   0 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.3 0.4

   sort(unique(data$colsample_bytree))
  0.3 0.5 1
```

My code is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(data, aes(x= colsample_bytree, y = best_F1, fill = as.factor(alpha))) +

geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, position=position_dodge(1)) + theme_economist() +
ggtitle("F1 for alpha and colsample_bytree")
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

and the following Warning:

```
Warning message:
"position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals"
```

Since the variable colsample_bytree takes 3 discrete values and the variable alpha takes 6 I would expect to see 3 groups of boxplots --each group comprised from 6 boxplots corresponding to the different alpa values and each group positioned at a different value of colsample_bytree,i.e. 0.3, 0.5 and 1.

I would expect the boxplots to not overlap just like in the example I cited.

Comment: Your example at the top uses a categorical x-axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to include `data$colsample_bytree <- as.factor(data$colsample_bytree)` before you plot your data with the `ggplot` command.